# XML binding tools for Android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-serialization

I would like to compare some XML binding tools for Android, however there does not seem to be many available. Any that are, are cumbersome or very limited in capability. What frameworks other than the [Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net) XML framework are available for the Android platform.

Here I am interested in frameworks that do all the heavy work, so KXML, DOM, and SAX are not really what I am looking for. Frameworks like JiBX and JAXB are more along the lines of what I am looking for.

Comment: Do you start with object and make XML or do you start with XML and make the objects?

Answer (score 3):

What you really want is the Simple XML Library which will work on Android.

I actually wrote a blog post explaining exactly how to use it: [you can find that here](http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/)

Edit: Lol, I just looked at who the author of this question was and I am pretty sure that ng is Niall himself, the person that wrote the Simple XML Library.

Answer (score 1):

I have used http://x-stream.github.io/.
Very simple to use and fast.

Answer (score 0):

The Jackson JSON project works on the Android platform. XML support is just in an experimental stage, but it should be part of your comparison, as it is the performance champion. No schema support.
http://jackson-users.ning.com/profiles/blogs/experimental-support-for

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use every XML databinding as long it is pure java.  XStream and Jackson are good choices ( xstream is really easy to use,  and jackson offers  high performance )

You just have to watch for pull-parsing model to prevent extensive memory consumption.

Main drawback from those libraries is size.  If you like to have really lightweight solution, 
you may opt for JSON format and use GSON pull parser.   I developed  simple databinding around pull parsing capabilities:

https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer

Feel free to use and comment

Comment: Not all databinding tools will work in Android because StAX missing. I've tried to use Jackson 2.2.x without any luck

Answer (score 0):

[JiBX](http://www.jibx.org) works great on android. JiBX already uses XMLPull, which is the default XML parser for android.

Just create your JiBX binding, include jibx-run.jar in your app and you are good to go.